# An exercise on Central Limit Theorem and Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dotsc$ be independent random variables with the common density $\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$, where $-\infty < x < \infty$.
>   Show that $(n^{0.5}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)/\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ converges to $Z$ in distribution, where $Z$ is a Normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1/2$. (Hint: Use Slusky's theorem.)

My idea is to show that $n^{0.5}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges to some normal r.v. in distribution while $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ converges to some constant number in probability so the whole thing would converge to a normal r.v.. But I have no idea how to show it and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Could anyone explain how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A further hint: divide top and bottom by $n$, i.e. look at $\frac{n^{-1/2} \sum_i X_i}{n^{-1} \sum_i X_i^2}$.

Comment: @Ian I got it! Thanks a lot!!